# why should I use cloned DOM that is not linked if I want my directive to repeat DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm reading [this article](http://triangular.io/blog/transclusion-transcludefn/) about transclusion and here is an extract from it:

> So if our directive should just duplicate some element several times
>   it could look like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transcludeFn) {
    var count = Math.abs(parseInt(attrs.simpleRepeat, 10) || 0);
    while (count--) {
        $transcludeFn(scope, function (clone) {
            // be sure elements are inserted
            // into html before linking
            element.after(clone);
        });
    }
}
```

I am confused about this comment inside the code:

> // be sure elements are inserted 
>     // into html before linking

Can you guys please explain me the need for inserting the elements before linking instead of doing like this?

```
while (count--) {
    var clone = $transcludeFn(scope, function (clone) {});
    element.after(clone);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that you are transcluding an element with a directive `foo`. `foo` doesn't and *shouldn't* know about whether it was transcluded or was placed directly where it belonged.

For example, `foo` might need to attach an event handler to its container in its `link` function, or it might `require: "^fooParent"` directive. For the latter example, imagine the following usage of `foo`:

```
<foo-parent>
  <foo></foo>
  <foo></foo>
</foo-parent>
```

Everything should work fine for `foo`.

But now, I want to get fancy and so I create a `double` directive that doubles its transcluded content:

```
<foo-parent>
  <double>
    <foo></foo>
  </double>
</foo-parent>
```

and here's part of its implementation:

```
transclude: true,
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
  var linkedClone1 = transclude(scope, function(clone){
     element.append(clone); // works fine
  });

  var linkedClone2 = transclude(scope, function(clone){});
  // fails before append, because required foo-parent is not found
  element.append(linkedClone2);
}
```

This second `transclude` invocation will fail for `foo`, because `foo`'s link phase will run before the cloned `foo` is appended to its parent.