# Odd behavior when using transclusion without cloning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

While experimenting with transclusion a bit, I wanted to see if the transcluded directive, which requires a certain parent directive controller, will be able to find it after being transcluded under the required parent.
The Directives i've used are the following:
There is a ParentOfParent directive which has transclude:true.
There is a directive Parent which is embedded into ParentOfParent directive template
There is a Child directive which requires Parent controller, and is being transcluded by ParentOfParent to be a child of Parent directive.

```
    'use strict';
angular
    .module('angularlabApp', [
    'ngRoute',
])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
        .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

'use strict';
angular.module('angularlabApp')
    .directive('parent', function () {
    return {
        controller: function () { },
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('Parent Link');
        }
    };
});

'use strict';

angular.module('angularlabApp')
  .directive('parentOfParent', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div id="prnt" parent></div>',
      transclude: true,
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs,_,transcludeFn){
        console.log('POP Link');
        element.find('#prnt').append(transcludeFn());

      }
    };
  });


'use strict';

angular.module('angularlabApp')
  .directive('child', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div></div>',
      restrict: 'EA',
      require:'^parent',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('Child Link');
      }
    };
  });


'use strict';
angular.module('angularlabApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
});
```

What i've encountered was an odd discrepancy between using transclusion function with and without cloning.
When I am using the transclusion function output (without passing the cloneFn) I am getting an error that the child directive cant find Parent Controller above it.
http://plnkr.co/edit/JteQpPMc6nbVNjRDHVZ2

However, when I am using it by passing cloneFn, everything works.

Is it even possible for transcluded directive to find required controller after being inserted below directive the controller belongs to?

Comment: Yes, this is the behavior - because at the time the transcluded content links, it is not under the required parent, so `require: "parent"` throws an error. What is the question though? Clearly, it ***is*** possible, as you mentioned - place the element in the `cloneAttachFn`, which happens prior to linking

Comment: I am trying to understand the difference between using clone and the original content. Why does it work with the cloned content but not the original

Comment: It's not a matter of "cloned" vs "original" - it is a matter of pre-linked content vs. post-linked. Here's my answer to a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29911348/968155

Comment: @NewDev great answer, although could you please elaborate a bit more?
Perhaps explain where the parent is being controller is being looked for in both cases?
As far as I understand, when cloneFn is passed, the content is being linked AFTER the callback completed running, as oppose to the case where the output of transclusion function is used. In later case, the returned template is already linked. Correct?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question exactly, but judging by your self-answer, you seem to understand the issue. The controller is being looked for in link-time. `cloneFn` is an opportunity to place the cloned contents in the DOM before they are linked and so things like `require` work correctly

Comment: awesome.thanks for validating.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29911348/968155) answer, and [this](http://triangular.io/blog/transclusion-transcludefn/) article, I finally understood what caused the difference.

When the output of the transclude function is used (without passing the clone callback), the output is already compiled and **LINKED**.

```
var linkedClone = $transcludeFn();
```

Since the linking already occurred, the copied directive already looked for the controller of the parent directive. Since the copied DOM node is still detached it, wont be able to find it.

On contrary, when the copied DOM subtree is received through clone callback, as explained in the article:

> Compile clone in child scope of directive’s scope and pass clone before calling all its linking functions

Hence, you get a chance to attach the copied DOM subtree BEFORE its being linked, thus allowing it to look for the controller above it when it is already in the DOM.